# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't work when going to page via page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-4

I googled like crazy, searched here on SO and tried a lot of things but nothing seems to be working.

**Problem:**

I have autocompletion in my Rals4 application, and the problem is that it doesn't work when I go to form page by links, but when I refresh that page it works.

The js.coffescript code is:

```
$(document).ready( ->
  $('#exercise_element_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#exercise_element_name').data('autocomplete-source')
    messages: {
      noResults: '',
      results: ->
    }
)
```

I also tried with

```
jQuery ->
  $('#exercise_element_name').autocomplete
    source: $('#exercise_element_name').data('autocomplete-source')
```

and a lot similar stuff, I have no idea what is going wrong here and I would really appreciate help.

Maybe I need to mention that I don't use ajax to get the autocomplete list, I generate list inside html, and also when page first opens (when autocomplete doesn't work) the list is there, but autocomplete doesn't work, only after refreshing the page or write direct link.

So it is not working when going to the page with autocomplete text_field by links on the page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so nobody answered so far, but I find the answer so here it is for others who my have that problem.

The problem was with Rails 4 turbolinks which are enabled by default. When you use them you can not longer lay on jquery.ready() function from js to fire on page load, so you need to use page:load instead or you can install [jquery.turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) which will bind page:load to query.ready().

More about this [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

Comment: thanks a lot Azaryan, I had the same issue with jquery-ui not working as expected. I installed the jquery-turbolinks gem and now the issue is solved.